# React es6 grammar

Tags: reactjs

```
const TodoList = ({ todos, onTodoClick }) => (
  <ul>
    {todos.map(todo =>
      <Todo
        key={todo.id}
        {...todo}
        onClick={() => onTodoClick(todo.id)}
      />
    )}
  </ul>
)
```

Here with the React. CreateClass change this way how to write, and then the above this kind of writing is ES6 grammar?

This code from here  http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Is this ES6? Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's written in ES6, but that's not a common React Component, that's a **stateless** React Component, which has some limitations.

You can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/@joshblack/stateless-components-in-react-0-14-f9798f8b992d#.1yo0colia)

Comment: It is more a **stateless functional** component. The syntax may evolve to include `state` as discussed in many React issues.